# Centering Text in Table Cell

Tags: tables

I have tried to center text within a cell in my table by defining a new column type = `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`

Yet in my MWE, my contents are still not centering

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{vonecount}
\setcounter{vonecount}{0}
\newcommand{\vone}{\stepcounter{vonecount}\thevonecount}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}} 
\cline{1-18}
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Section One}                           &   
\multicolumn{17}{>{\centering}p{4in}|}{Part One - Synonyms} \\ 
\cline{1-18}
Question \#     &   
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone \\
\cline{2-18}
Correct Answer  & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A \\
Your Answer     & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
\cline{1-18}
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Section One}                                       &   
\multicolumn{17}{>{\centering}p{4in}|}{Part Two - Sentence Completions} \\ 
\cline{1-18}
Question \#     &   
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone \\
\cline{2-18}
Correct Answer  &   
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A \\
Your Answer     & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Scores}                 &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Correct}            &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Total}              &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Stanine}            &   
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{Percentile Rank}    \\
\cline{2-18}
                        &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   &   
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{}   \\
\cline{2-18}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean to have columns that are just two millimeters wide? Have you considered writing `\multicolumn{17}{c}{Part One - Synonyms}` for the header cell?

Comment: You are correct on the multicolumn. I forgot to change that after some adjustments I had made. Either way, I was speaking of the numbers established by the counters centered in their cells.

Comment: I think that they are centred relative to the width you have allowed. But 2mm is just not enough space for it to work properly. Could you not just use `c` in this case?

Comment: You are correct `c` does work, and fixes the problem. But the table is then too wide, past the textwidth. Would the solution be to change the environment type? I have switched it to 2.9mm (which keeps it within the text block), but there is still a slight discrepancy in center spacing in the double-digit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain what you want with the `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array, colortbl, tabularx}

\newcommand\redhline{\arrayrulecolor{red}\hline\arrayrulecolor{black}}
\newcommand\vredrule{\color{red}\vrule}
\newcounter{vonecount}
\setcounter{vonecount}{0}
\newcommand{\vone}{\stepcounter{vonecount}\thevonecount}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. \\
%
%\begin{center}
%\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
%\begin{tabular}{r|*{17}{c|}}
%\redhline
%\multicolumn{1}{!{\vredrule}r!{\vredrule}}{Section One} &
%\multicolumn{17}{c!{\vredrule}}{Part One -- Synonyms} \\
%\redhline
%Question \# &
%\vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone
%& \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone \\
%\cline{2-18}
%Correct Answer &
%A & A &A & A & A & A & A & A & A &
%A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
%Your Answer & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
%\redhline
%\multicolumn{1}{!{\vredrule}r!{\vredrule}}{Section One} &
%\multicolumn{17}{c!{\vredrule}}{Part Two -- Sentence Completions} \\
%\arrayrulecolor{red}\hline\arrayrulecolor{black}
%Question \# &
%\vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone
%& \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone \\
%\cline{2-18}
%Correct Answer &
%A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A &
%A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
%Your Answer & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
%\redhline
%\multicolumn{1}{!{\vredrule}r!{\vredrule}}{\multirow{2}{*}{Scores}}&
%\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Correct} &
%\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Total} &
%\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Stanine} &
%\multicolumn{5}{c!{\vredrule}}{Percentile Rank} \\
%\cline{2-18}
%\multicolumn{1}{!{\vredrule}r!{\vredrule}}{}&
%\multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c!{\vredrule}}{} \\
%\redhline
%\end{tabular}
%\end{center}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r|*{17}{X|}}
\redhline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\vredrule}r!{\vredrule}}{Section One} &
\multicolumn{17}{c!{\vredrule}}{Part One -- Synonyms} \\
\redhline
Question \# &
\vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone
& \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone \\
\cline{2-18}
Correct Answer &
A & A &A & A & A & A & A & A & A &
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
Your Answer & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\redhline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\vredrule}r!{\vredrule}}{Section One} &
\multicolumn{17}{c!{\vredrule}}{Part Two -- Sentence Completions} \\
\arrayrulecolor{red}\hline\arrayrulecolor{black}
Question \# &
\vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone
& \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone & \vone \\
\cline{2-18}
Correct Answer &
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A &
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
Your Answer & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\redhline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\vredrule}r!{\vredrule}}{\multirow{2}{*}{Scores}}&
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Correct} &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Total} &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Stanine} &
\multicolumn{5}{c!{\vredrule}}{Percentile Rank} \\
\cline{2-18}
\multicolumn{1}{!{\vredrule}r!{\vredrule}}{}&
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c!{\vredrule}}{} \\
\redhline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]